# Search and find a string in an Array

Tags: php, arrays

Hello all I have an array which contains id and name and I have a string with a coma saperated ids.
What I want is that for each id in string, find the name in array and print the name.

```
  $query=select name,id from table where something='match'
  $array1=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
```

Now I have another string with values     `1,2,3,4,5....`

I want to find the name for each id in the string from the array.

Please advice me something and help me t get this.

```
 var_dump($_SESSION['deps_array']);

   array(12) { [0]=> string(1) "2" ["did"]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(8) "Accounts" ["name"]=> string(8) "Accounts" [2]=> string(9) "photo.png" ["photo"]=> string(9) "photo.png" [3]=> string(0) "" ["dabout"]=> string(0) "" [4]=> string(0) "" ["fname"]=> string(0) "" [5]=> string(0) "" ["lname"]=> string(0) "" }





 $array=$_SESSION['deps_array'];
 $res = search('3,6', $array);
 echo "Result:".PHP_EOL;
 var_dump($res);
```

RESULT

```
 Warning: Illegal string offset 'did' in     /Applications/AMPPS/www/pros/site/test.php on line 12

 Warning: Illegal string offset 'did' in /Applications/AMPPS/www/pros/site/test.php on line 12
```

function

```
function search($ids,$array) {
$ids=substr($ids,1);
$idArray = explode(",", $ids);
$result = Array();
foreach($idArray as $id)
{

   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
       $iddd=$val['did'];
       if ( $iddd=== $id) {
           echo $val.','.$val;
       }
   }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function below like `search($ids, $array1);` where `$ids` variable contain your values `1,2,3,4,5, n`.

**Function**

```
function search($ids, $array) {

   $idArray = explode(",", $ids);
   $result = Array();

   foreach($idArray as $id)
   {

       foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
           if ($val['id'] === $id) {
               array_push($result, $val['name']);//this line is updated
           }
       }

   }

   return $result;

}//end function
```

Inside the function, `$ids` variable is converted to an array and outer foreach loop through every id and try to find the expected id in values. If found, then push it to a result array and finally `$result` array is returned from the array. This will return the matched values only.

Disclaimer: *I havent tested the function but it should work.*

**UPDATE**

Considering your result `$array1` is same as this array:

```
$array = [    
    ['id'=>'1', 'Name'=>'Name 1'],
    ['id'=>'2', 'Name'=>'Name 2'],
    ['id'=>'3', 'Name'=>'Name 3'],
    ['id'=>'4', 'Name'=>'Name 4'],
    ['id'=>'5', 'Name'=>'Name 5'],
    ['id'=>'6', 'Name'=>'Name 6'],
    ['id'=>'7', 'Name'=>'Name 7'],
    ['id'=>'8', 'Name'=>'Name 8'],
    ['id'=>'9', 'Name'=>'Name 9'] ];

function search($ids, $array) {

   $idArray = explode(",", $ids);
   $result = Array();

   foreach($idArray as $id)
   {

       foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
           if ($val['id'] === $id) {
               echo "name:".$val['Name'];
               array_push($result, $val['Name']);
           }
       }

   }

   return $result;

}//end function

// test
$res = search('3,6', $array);

echo "Result:".PHP_EOL;
var_dump($res);
```

*Result Screenshot*

[image]

Comment: Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in /includes/functions.php on line 1951

Comment: My `explode()` function was wrong.. try this ` $idArray = explode("," ,$ids);` and let me know.  I've updated the code.

Comment: Without updating original answer.. you can share code or other resource in comment. Your code:
i have tried this
    'function search($ids) {
      $array=$_SESSION['array'];
       $ids=substr($ids,1);
       $idArray = explode(",", $ids);
     $result = Array();
     foreach($idArray as $id)
       {
        foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
            if ($val['id'] === $id) {
                array_push($result, $key);
              }
           }

          }
 
          return $result;

         }//end function

       $_SESSION['array'] = mysqli_fetch_array($query);`

Comment: it is still not working what di i put in id $val['id']  i am putting the id it is not working

Comment: Can you `var_dump()` your query result `$array1` and share in your question by updating it? I can then test the code and try to help you out.

Comment: What i have is that i am selecting name,id,name2,gender by a query then putting the mysqli_fetch_array($query) in session and now i want to match the id and print the names out of the session array.

Comment: if i print this foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
               echo $val.','.$val;
       } it prints all values of array like name,id,gender,name2 etc... i just want names only

Comment: @sonamSharma updated my function and answer.. If you want names only.. you need `array_push($result, $val['Name']);` Check the answer.. I believe you can reproduce it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95829/discussion-between-ariful-haque-and-sonam-sharma).